# TypeORM ManyToOne FindOne fires multiple unecessary queries

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I have a db table design like so:

Table Appointments:

id| start_time| patientId |.. etc other fields |

And another table which is Patient table:

id| name | last_name | .. etc other fields |

On my appointment entity I have this defintion:

```
@OneToMany(() => AppointmentEntity, (appt) => appt.patient)
appointments: Relation<AppointmentEntity>[];
```

Here is what I'm trying to do, given an appointment id, fetch appointment details as well as patients first name, should be very straight forward. This is what I ended up doing:

```
 async getAppt(apptId: any) {
    return this.apptRepo.findOne({
      relations: ['patient'],
      where: { id: apptId },
      select: {
        id: true,
        start_time: true
        patient: {
          name: true,
        },
      },
    });
  }
```

This does give me expected results, but for whatever reason I am running two completely unnecessary db queries, instead of one. This is what gets run each time `getAppt` is executed:

```
query: SELECT DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."AppointmentEntity_id" AS "ids_AppointmentEntity_id" FROM (SELECT "AppointmentEntity"."id" AS "AppointmentEntity_id", "AppointmentEntity"."start_time" AS "AppointmentEntity_start_time", "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient"."name" AS "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient_name" FROM "appointments" "AppointmentEntity" LEFT JOIN "patients" "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient" ON "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient"."id"="AppointmentEntity"."patientId" WHERE ("AppointmentEntity"."id" = $1)) "distinctAlias" ORDER BY "AppointmentEntity_id" ASC LIMIT 1 -- PARAMETERS: ["appt_id_xxx"]
query: SELECT "AppointmentEntity"."id" AS "AppointmentEntity_id", "AppointmentEntity"."start_time" AS "AppointmentEntity_start_time", "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient"."name" AS "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient_name" FROM "appointments" "AppointmentEntity" LEFT JOIN "patients" "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient" ON "AppointmentEntity__AppointmentEntity_patient"."id"="AppointmentEntity"."patientId" WHERE ( ("AppointmentEntity"."id" = $1) ) AND ( "AppointmentEntity"."id" IN ($2) ) -- PARAMETERS: ["appt_id_xxx","appt_id_xxx"
```

What I really wanted my query to execute is (one query):

```
select b.id, b.start_time, p.name  from appointments b
inner join patients p on p.id = b."patientId" 
where b.id = 'appt_id_xxx';
```

Or something similar to this, it's fine without aliases "b" and "p", it's just how I write queries, but this is all it takes. I don't get this `distinctAlias` nonsence and why there are two db queries.

Can you advise on how to accomplish one query (or similar), like shown above? thanks!

Comment: Since you are using an ORM, you can't alter its inner queries assigned to each of the functions. Here, whatever the relation you have initialised while forming tables/schemas one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many, will work behind the scene to form queries. The two queries are there because the masking or aliasing works dynamically and pre-decided. You can obviously initialize foreign_keys & tables aliasing for relations manually if you want that.

Comment: @Rohit Khandelwal can you show an example of that?

Comment: I have added an answer for you. Although, you can better explore their docs and search specific examples for things you want to extract out and do your stuff. There are other good ORMs in the market as well, you can try them if type-checking is not the constraint here.

Comment: Some of the prebuilt behaviour of TypeORM caused problems with my projects. The solution was to move to que .queryBuilder() always, that's the only way to keep things as consistent as possible

Comment: Issue is here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5694

Answer (score 1):

For aliasing, you can use the following [example in library docs](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#what-are-aliases-for), as reference:

> ##### What are aliases for?
>
> We used `createQueryBuilder("user")`. But what is "user"? It's just a regular SQL alias. We use aliases
> everywhere, except when we work with selected data.
>
> `createQueryBuilder("user")` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> createQueryBuilder().select("user").from(User, "user")
> ```
>
> Which will result in the following SQL query:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... FROM users user
> ```
>
> In this SQL query, users is the table name, and user is an alias we
> assign to this table. Later we use this alias to access the table:
>
> ```
> createQueryBuilder()
>     .select("user")
>     .from(User, "user")
>     .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
> ```
>
> Which produces the following SQL query:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... FROM users user WHERE user.name = 'Timber'
> ```
>
> See, we used the users table by using the user alias we assigned when
> we created a query builder.
>
> One query builder is not limited to one alias, they can have multiple
> aliases. Each select can have its own alias, you can select from
> multiple tables each with its own alias, you can join multiple tables
> each with its own alias. You can use those aliases to access tables
> are you selecting (or data you are selecting).

Here `createQueryBuilder` is a function available in the library to create custom queries.

By going through their docs I can assume they rely on `left-join` the most. There is a function available `leftJoinAndSelect` in support of `createQueryBuilder`.

For a complete reference, you can go through the docs [How to create and use a QueryBuilder](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#how-to-create-and-use-a-querybuilder).

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is **eager loading** here and it seems like this is not configurable in the query as for now (if we can belive this issue: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7142).

However, you can set eager loading on the model level by adding it to the relationship definition.

```
@OneToMany(() => AppointmentEntity, (appt) => appt.patient, { eager: true })
appointments: Relation<AppointmentEntity>[];
```

Be careful with that, it will now always load it eagerly.

---

For more information have a look at this doc: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations.md

Answer (score 0):

When you use TypeORM and use the property `@ManyToOne()` but also you're using `createQueryBuilder` for make any request into database you must use `leftJoinAndSelect()` property.

Beside, if you're using any property from findOne or findOneBy Or all properties for find* you must set the `eager: true`.

Then:

```
@OneToMany(() => AppointmentEntity, (appt) => appt.patient, { eager: true })appointments: Relation<AppointmentEntity>[];
```

I hope that my response can help you!